# Splash Screens do not work on phonegap build

Tags: cordova, splash-screen, phonegap-build

I have been working on my first app game, and everything seems to work fine, but I can't finish the detail of splash screens. I have read and searched Google endlessly but I can't solve it.

I have included all the images in the `res` folder and everything is according to the route configured in the `config.xml`. When I run Phonegap build, what happens is that a small instant white screen appears with a header and a black area with the name of my app that I put in the `config.xml` (`<name> Superfreak </name>`). I've tried different things I have searched google but nothing works for me.

This is my `config.xml` code:
https://github.com/msnzapps/asdfddasdf/blob/master/config.xml